# ads in visual studio web running

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I use asp.net mvc with IIS

I've not used any link to other site for script or css

When I Run visual studio my page has a box with ads.

It's not there before

See the images

What is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It says "ads not by this site" on your page. Check your browser plugins and scan your machine for malware.

Comment: thank you ! it's right,i disable some extensions